# VS 2013 telling me Use lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dictionary, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

My issue comes with the layers.Add part.  I'm brand new to MVC, Razor, Linq and Telerik's KendoUI using the Map widget. the layers.Add() function gets a green squiggly line with message "Use lambda expression". Why am I getting this? Thanks for your help. [link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJtx7.jpg)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Map()
      .Name("map")
      .Center(39.6924, -97.3370)
      .Zoom(4)
      .Layers(layers =>
      {
          layers.Add()
              .Style(style => style.Fill(fill => fill.Opacity(0.7)))
              .Type(MapLayerType.Shape)
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .GeoJson()
                  .Read(read => read.Url(Url.Content("~/Scripts/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.js")))
              );
      })
      .Events(events => events
           .ShapeCreated("onShapeCreated")
           .ShapeMouseEnter("onShapeMouseEnter")
           .ShapeMouseLeave("onShapeMouseLeave")
        )
)
```

Comment: Will VS2013 rewrite it to a lambda for you? (R# will, so when I have a doubt I let it do the rewrite and then see which I prefer :)

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Edited the question.  But why am i getting this? [link](http://i.imgur.com/iNmYPIl.jpg)

Comment: Do you get an error when actually running the page?  VisualStudio sometimes has some trouble with Razor and displaying errors/squigglies where it's not really an issue.  Razor is very difficult to parse(an admission from one of Microsoft's) and so things like this and formatting are sometimes hit or miss.

Comment: Perhaps this is it then.  The page runs (not the way I want it) so naturally I would start with the compiler type errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE is simply suggesting that you could shorten your lambda. Suppose `F` is some function that returns void. Then both of the following are the same:

```
x => { F(x); }
x => F(x)
```

So your code could be shortened by replacing this:

```
layers =>
{
    layers.Add()
        .Style(style => style.Fill(fill => fill.Opacity(0.7)))
        .Type(MapLayerType.Shape)
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .GeoJson()
            .Read(read => read.Url(Url.Content("~/Scripts/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.js")))
        );
}
```

With this:

```
layers => layers.Add()
    .Style(style => style.Fill(fill => fill.Opacity(0.7)))
    .Type(MapLayerType.Shape)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .GeoJson()
        .Read(read => read.Url(Url.Content("~/Scripts/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.js")))
     )
```

For legibility reasons you may or may not want to actually make this change.

Comment: I tried this, but got 6 errors because it wasn't contained

Comment: @tshoemake Make sure you're getting rid of exactly: (1) the `{` before the lambda body, (2) the `;` after the lambda body's statement, (3) the `}` after the lambda body. If you do that you shouldn't get any syntax errors.